# Select/extract columns based on the values on a certain row

Tags: awk

Here is an example text file:

```
A B C D E F G
1 2 3 4 5 6 7
2 3 4 5 6 7 8
3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

I would like to extract specific columns based on the values on the 3rd row, that is, 2 3 4 5 6 7 8.
Let's say, I would like to extract all the columns with a value on the 3rd row larger than 5. That will be the final 3 columns. Hence, my goal is to select and generate the following:

```
E F G
5 6 7
6 7 8
7 8 9
```

Here is my code:

```
NR==3 {
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        if ($i > 5)   x[j++] = i
    }
}
NR>= 1 {
  for (i=0 ;  i < j-1; i++ )
     printf("%s ",$x[i])
  printf("%s\n",$x[j-1])
}
```

However, this generates the following:

```
A B C D E F G
1 2 3 4 5 6 7
6 7 8
7 8 9
```

What did I miss?

Comment: your problem is that lines 1 and 2 are processed before line 3, and go through the `NR>=1` code block, with no initialization for `j` and `x`

Comment: I believe you have "rows" (lines of the file?) and "columns" somehow mixed up... and I see no way to use the contents of the third _line_ without stashing away the first two somehow to process later. Or is the processing to begin with the fourth?

Comment: [This question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/58851/process-last-line-first-using-awk) is a good place to start

Comment: Thanks, guys. I was hoping to use awk only to accomplish the task. But since awk scans the file line by line, my alternative is to simplely arrange my the criteria line/row  (3rd line in my example) to be the header for awk to scan it first. I have been hesitant to take that approach since my actual file is quite large.

Comment: The other solution is a two pass filtering, as described in the question I mentioned above.

Comment: Good idea. Vincent. But the 2 step approaches might be similar to adding a header line, in terms of computing time and efficient, no? Thanks for bearing with me for my awk clumsiness.

Comment: Though it's working for me, I am trying to improve the second half of my codes starting NR>=1 (now I changed it to NR >=3). I still have much to learn about awk. would you mind pointing out how initiations should be added to make it clearer? My several attempts couldn't get it to work as soon as I added initiations.

Comment: You should edit your answer and update your code, to avoid flooding the comments, and get newcomers straight to the point.

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
code=$(
  awk '
    NR == 3 {
      for (i=1; i<=NF; i++)
        if ($i > 5) { printf "%s", sep "$" i; sep="," }
      exit sep == ""
    }' file
) &&
  awk "{print $code}" file
```

That is call `awk` twice on the same file. The first one reads the 3rd line to construct code for the second `awk` invocation. It exits after processing the 3rd line, so won't read the whole file fully. It outputs something like `$5,$6,$7`, so the next `awk` invocation becomes:

```
awk '{print $5,$6,$7}' file
```

Comment: This is clever ! Thank you so much. Really appreciated !

Answer (score 0):

I got another awk solution to share :

```
cat > extract.columns.awk   
BEGIN {   
  infil=ARGV[1]  
    while (getline < infil > 0)  
      if (++n==3)  
      {  
        for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)  
            if ($(i) > 5) x[++j]=i  
    }  
close(infil)    
}  
{  
    for (i=1;i<j;i++)  
    printf("%s ",$x[i])  
    printf("%s\n",$x[j])  
}
```

awk -f extract.columns.awk file

Comment: You may want to exit at the end of your BEGIN statement if `j == 0` to avoid processing the file if there's nothing to display.

Comment: Thank you, Stephane ! Do you mean adding " if (j==0) exit " at the end of the BEGIN block? Would you mind explaining a bit more?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure to mention the file name twice as mentioned in the below code

```
awk 'NR == FNR{if(FNR == line) {for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) {if($i > lmt) a[i]} close(FILENAME)} next}
{for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) {for(i in a) {out = (out == "") ? $i : (out FS $i)}}
  print out; out=""}' line=3 lmt=5 file file
```